# Control Visibility autochanges when building

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls

Hello dear users of Stackoverflow.

I have a project made in Winforms where i have a problem with an usercontrol I have created. The usercontrol consists of some layoutpanels, controls etc. It's intended to be used as a settings controller. It has some properties used to change the design/layout of the usercontrol, such as a "ShowTitle" property og "ShowDefault" property, which is default set to 'true'. The properties get/set references directly to the underlying control.visibility.

The usercontrols is placed in to a tabs control to give a overview of the settings, but (allmost) everytime I rebuild the solution the usercontrols in tab pages not currently shown in the designer have all their "Show..." properties changed to 'false'.

If I remove the setting in the designer:
this.SpawnRate.ShowDefaultButton = false;
if pops up again when i rebuild.

I really don't know whats goes wrong, and I have bug hunted the code for hours. Does anyone have a clue where the problem might lie?

//Nautious

**EDIT:** it is only properties referencing to control.visibility properties who changes their value

**UPDATE:**

Found the problem... Apprently I can't return the Control.Visible value directly like this:

```
bool ShowBtn
{
get{ return Btn_Default.Visible; }
set{ Btn_Default.Visible = value; }
}
```

but had to have a local variable:

```
bool ShowBtn
{
get{ return _ShowDefault; }
set{ Btn_Default.Visible = value;
     _ShowDefault = value; }
}
bool _ShowDefault = true;
```

after changing, the problem no longer occurred.

anyone know why the problem is there?

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oh the irony! Posted after 3 hours of bughunting. And found the problem 30 min after posting.. 
The problem was apparently that it didn't like the property get returning the control.visible value directly, i had to have a local variable i returned, and kept in sync with the control.visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... Apprently I can't return the Control.Visible value directly like this:

```
bool ShowBtn
{
    get{ return Btn_Default.Visible; }
    set{ Btn_Default.Visible = value; }
}
```

but had to have a local variable:

```
bool ShowBtn
{
    get{ return _ShowDefault; }
    set
    {
        Btn_Default.Visible = value;
        _ShowDefault = value; 
    }
}
bool _ShowDefault = true;
```

after changing, the problem no longer occurred.